# SOLR OR query PHP

Tags: php, solr

The code I currently have looks like this:

```
$query -> addFilterQuery(array(
    'key'=>feature,
    'query'=>'Features:1,7 Ghz',
    'tag'=>'include'
))
```

What I need is both the results for 1,7 Ghz and 2,0 Ghz. 
Adding another filter query uses an AND operator, but what I need is an OR operator.

I've read that the `setQuery()` function does use an OR operator, but I cannot figure out how to work that out with multiple values.

I've been looking for this for a while, but I can't find any documentation on this.

If anything is unclear please let me know (not my native language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plain Lucene syntax should work fine, depending on the escaping performed by the Solr library you're using:

```
'query' => 'Features:("1,7 Ghz" OR "2,0 Ghz")'
```

This can also be combined as multiple separate statements referring to a field:

```
'query' => 'Features:"1,7 Ghz" OR Features:"2,0 Ghz"'
```

Comment: Tried something similar before, but I guess the syntax wasn't right. This works like a charm, thanks!